# React Component with Memory Leak

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I have a piece of legacy code, which renders a react component on the server on every request, which makes it obvious there is a memory leak. I have corner the problem up to this code:

```
  componentWillMount: function () {
    var onLogin = this.props.onLogin || function () {},
        onLogout = this.props.onLogout || function () {};

    this.on('authChange', function () {
      console.log('user authenticated:', this.state.isAuthenticated);
      return this.state.isAuthenticated
              ? onLogin(this.state)
              : onLogout(this.state);
    }.bind(this));
  },
```

I believe that on every request the `this` object is storing a new listener, but I don't get why the `this` element is not being marked as garbage when the rendering of the component is done.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to unbind the `authChange` handler before the component is unmounted. You can do this in [`componentWillUnmount`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#unmounting-componentwillunmount).

Since you're creating the handler function using the first props that are passed in, you should save it to a property so you can unbind it later:

```
  componentWillMount: function () {
    var onLogin = this.props.onLogin || function () {},
        onLogout = this.props.onLogout || function () {};

    this.authChange = function () {
      console.log('user authenticated:', this.state.isAuthenticated);
      return this.state.isAuthenticated
              ? onLogin(this.state)
              : onLogout(this.state);
    }.bind(this);

    this.on('authChange', this.authChange);
  },

  componentWillUnmount: function () {
      this.off('authChange', this.authChange);
      this.authChange = null;
  }
```

Note that when I saw `this.on` I thought you might be using jQuery but it's not clear how that would be the case. My answer uses `this.off` to detach the event listener but you should use whatever the corresponding method is in your framework.

Comment: But shouldn't the `this` component be marked as garbage anyway when the `renderToString()` function is completed?

Answer (score 3):

I would move your function into `componentDidMount` and add cleanup on `componentWillUnmount`

**Important**: `componentWillMount` is called on the **server** and **client**, but `componentDidMount` is only called on the **client**.

If you’re using `eventListeners`, `setInterval` or other functions that needs to be cleaned, put them in `componentDidMount`. The server will not call `componentWillUnmount` and is usually the cause of memory leaks.